# Synchronise colors between plot and legend

Tags: r, igraph

I have this command to produce a network graph from igraph:

```
plot(ig, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(ig),vertex.label=NA,vertex.label.color="black",vertex.frame.color="black",edge.color="black", vertex.color=rainbow(9)[data2$Group], main="MB Network")
```

The data2 is another object containing information on groupings of the vertices in the igraph object ig. I wanted to color the vertices by their groupings and then put a legend for group color guidelines so I used the command:

```
legend("topleft",legend=unique(data2$Group),col=rainbow(9)[data2$Group])
```

However, the colors used in the legend does not match with the colors of the plot. How should I correct this?

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example? That will help both in understanding what you mean and helping us to troubleshoot. One possibility is that the colors are the same but not in the right order. If so, I wonder if `data2$Group` is a factor and the plot is sorting them by the level of the factor and the legend by the order after `unique`. Perhaps try `levels` instead of `unique`.

Comment: The problem is in the legend : you should replace `rainbow(9)[data2$Group]` by the colors that are actually used, so I guess `rainbow(9)`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Resh that `RColorBrewer` provides excellent color palettes !

Here is an example on a famous cubical graph

```
require(igraph)
require(RColorBrewer)
```

I would externally define the palette first, I chose four colors in the palette called "Accent". Each one of the color is then associated to the eight vertices according to a factor called Group. The levels of the factor are set on purpose to G, P, O and Y because the colors are green, purple, orange and yellow. This will help us know if the colors are right in both the graph and the legend.

```
pal <- brewer.pal(4,"Accent")
g <- make_graph("Cubical")
Group <- gl(4, 2, labels = c("G","P","O","Y"))
vertex.col <- pal[Group]

plot(g, 
     layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(g),
     vertex.label.color="black",
     vertex.frame.color="black",
     edge.color="black", 
     vertex.color=vertex.col, 
     main="Cubical")

legend("topleft",bty = "n",
       legend=levels(Group),
       fill=pal, border=NA)
```

And the result...

[image: Cubical example with legend]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, everyone for your inputs!

I somehow corrected the problem by using fill=rainbow(9)[unique(data2$Group)] for the legend.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package I have used in past called RColorBrewer which creates color pallets for you. Have you taken a look at it?

- http://earlglynn.github.io/RNotes/package/RColorBrewer/index.html
- https://moderndata.plot.ly/create-colorful-graphs-in-r-with-rcolorbrewer-and-plotly/

Once the colors are matched or same then the legend will also be of the same color.

Hope this helps.