# Adding legend in igraph plot in R

Tags: r, plot, cluster-computing, legend, igraph

I have a cluster plot (with 13 clusters) created by igraph in R. Each cluster has a different color. But I have not idea how add a legend with the name of each cluster and its correspondent color.
I don,t want the name of the node and its color (thousands of sequences)

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197910/synchronise-colors-between-plot-and-legend